# how to apply FIND WHOLE WORD ONLY in mysql query

Tags: mysql

sample table and records are given as follows:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivjCb.png)

how to select those records ONLY contains "2"("23","22"...don't count)???
as, the expected result set is {1,2,3}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a really bad data format.  You are storing lists of numbers in a single field.  Here are some reasons why this is a bad idea:

- Storing numbers as strings is a bad idea.
- Storing multiple values in a single column is a bad idea.
- Not declaring foreign key relationships is a bad idea.
- Relational databases are not very good at string manipulation, so storing values as strings is a bad idea.
- Such queries (in general) cannot be optimized using indexes, another bad idea.

So, your data structure is a bad, bad, bad, bad, bad idea.  You need to learn about junction tables and the right way to store lists in a relational database.

That said, sometime we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  If this is the case, you can use `find_in_set()`, a MySQL-specific function:

```
where find_in_set(2, field) > 0
```

Comment: thank u so much on this answer. as you said , i'm new in this bad project and confused about the design. but i'm not authorized to alter this db. again, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX to create your own queries, the following code is taken from the mysql official documentation:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '^2$';
```

[Here is the link to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)